# Button image not changing on clicking until i click on another button in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to making a popup that asks user to rate item.
But when I click on one of the buttons the image does not change until I press another button.

```
let selectedStar = UIImage(named:"004-star-selected.png")
let star = UIImage(named: "001-star.png")
@IBAction func rating(_ sender: UIButton) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let tag = sender.tag
        for i in 10...14{
            let view = self.view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
            if i <= tag{
                view.setImage(self.selectedStar, for: UIControlState.normal)
            }else{
                view.setImage(self.star, for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The use of `DispatchQueue.main.async` is pointless here.

Comment: thank you, but it's still not working

Comment: It is possible that the button's `UIControlState` is not `.normal` until a different button is hit, it is probably in a `.highlighted` or `.selected` state. Try print statements on your `view.state` to see whats going on. Are you using `TouchUpInside` for your `IBAction` set in storyboard? You probably see it after clicking a different button because it returns to `.normal` after you "select" a different button. Your setting your image ONLY for the .normal control state.

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the tags in xib file ? Make sure each button has tags from 10...14. If you copy a button in xib and paste it, it will retain the old tag.

You could assign separate images for `.normal` and `.selected` states and update the `isSelected` value. You can do this in the `xib` file itself and in the IBAction you would do something like `button.isSelected = true`.

Comment: I already tried to change the state of button still output is same I also delete the previous buttons and insert new one's but I still get same output